# Codeigniter 4 project I hosted online showing No input file specified

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

The codeigniter 4 project I hosted online showing No input file specified, when i click on any anchor, some of the design on the web page not working as well, like some pictures and the fontawesome.

this .htaccess code is added to redirect to public yet the issue persist

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: one can only guess as your question doesn't show how your anchors are built, or how your images are linked, etc,. show some **relevant** html of your view. Anyway I guess `$config['base_url'] setting is wrong? You might also have had http protocol for localhost and https now for production

Comment: You can simply put all of your files inside the public folder, inside your public_html (if that is your hosts root folder). And keep all the other files/folders above public_html. Effectively changing your public folder to you public_html folder. Then you just use the normal .htaccess file. Nothing else changes.

Comment: Provide your folder structure and anchor link